# Showing a non-blocking window/popup/dialog-box/notification in Perl without TK

Tags: perl, modal-dialog

I wish to execute a Perl script (without Tk) which should show a non-blocking notification (via window/dialog/popup/notification, etc). Currently, I have tried using:

- Dialog box
- Notify using Win32::GUI.

In both cases, the window is blocked for user input.
Also, if there is any option using Windows' system commands, please do mention that as well.

The perl script is a standalone script executed on windows.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? What kind of stuff are you using in general? So this is on Windows, with a window-based application, right? Not web. Your use of the word _script_ is misleading. Please clarify the question a bit.

Comment: Its pure Perl with no CPAN library. I am executing it on Windows cmd prompt.

Comment: So it's not window-based? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Assume I have a perl file that just prints hello. Now, I wish to show the hello in  a non-blocking window. Let me know if this clarifies he question. I run it from cmd.exe

Answer (score 1):

Use a blocking notification, but run it from a child process after a `fork`.

```
sub dialog {
    my $msg = shift;
    if (fork() == 0) {
        my_Win32_GUI_function_to_display_dialog($msg);
        exit;
    }
}
```